# How to detect number of elements has text start with special word using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a tag like below:

```
<section id="sec">
   <div id="item1">item1</div>
   <div id="item2">item2</div>
   <div id="item3">item3</div>
   <div id="abcitem1">abcitem1</div>
</section>
```

I want to check how many div tags contextText start with `item`. May I know is there any easier way that writes for condition and count them one by one(like Jquery)?

Comment: "*...is there any easier way*" - is there an easier way than what? You've not posted any attempts, you've demonstrated no research or effort and haven't explained where you're getting stuck.

Comment: @DavidThomas: Excusme?! I googled and look for other similar question since it was not available when I posted this question. The reason is that it might be useful for someone else.

Comment: And yet you showed no attempts at writing this yourself, and didn't mention any research or attempts to implement any of the results of your research.

Comment: @DavidThomas: There is no reason for me to lay. Are u the one teaching at Sheffield Hallam University? if yes, I will email my code in next 12 hours.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `.filter()` to filtering selected elements and use regex in `.match()` to check existence of `item` in element text.

```js
var count = $("#sec div").filter(function(){
  return $(this).text().match(/^item/);
}).length;
console.log(count);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="sec">
   <div id="item1">item1</div>
   <div id="item2">item2</div>
   <div id="item3">item3</div>
   <div id="abcitem1">abcitem1</div>
</section>
```

Comment: `.*` in the regex is unnecessary

Answer (score 3):

```
var res=0;
$( "#sec div" ).each(function( index ) {
 var str=  $(this).text() ;
  if(str.startsWith("item")==true){
  res++;
  }

});

console.log(res); //returns 3
```

Answer (score 2):

Without any jQuery or regex

```js
var nodes = document.querySelectorAll('#sec div')
var count = 0
nodes.forEach(node => count += node.innerText.startsWith('item'))
console.log(count)
```

```html
<section id="sec">
   <div id="item1">item1</div>
   <div id="item2">item2</div>
   <div id="item3">item3</div>
   <div id="abcitem1">abcitem1</div>
</section>
```

it's possible to add booleans to a number, `true` means 1 and `false` means 0

Comment: Note that not all browsers support forEach on a node list

Answer (score 2):

You could use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) function to get the occurrence of elements which start with `'item'`.

This is a native javascript solution, which uses [startsWith](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith), so you do not have to mess around with regular expressions.

```js
var childDivs = document.getElementById('sec')
           .getElementsByTagName('div');

var counter = Array.from(childDivs)
  .reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {
    if (currentValue.innerHTML.startsWith('item')) {
      return accumulator = accumulator + 1;    
    }
    return accumulator;
}, 0);

console.log( counter );
```

```html
<section id="sec">
   <div id="item1">item1</div>
   <div id="item2">item2</div>
   <div id="item3">item3</div>
   <div id="abcitem1">abcitem1</div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a pure JS way to count it.

```js
function checkItemsCount(section) {
  if (!section) return 0;
  const sec = document.querySelector(section);
  const items = sec.querySelectorAll('div');
  let count = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    if (/^item/.test(items[i].innerText)) count++;
  }
  return count;
}

console.log(checkItemsCount('#sec'));
```

```html
<section id="sec">
  <div id="item1">item1</div>
  <div id="item2">item2</div>
  <div id="item3">item3</div>
  <div id="abcitem1">abcitem1</div>
</section>
```

Comment: `.*` in the regex is unnecessary